# Bash python wrapper script that logs all the calls and the output to a file

Tags: python, bash

I am looking for generic bash (could be python also) wrapper that can be used to be called instead of the original program and that will call the original program and:

- logs the calling command line
- logs stdout and stderr, but without hiding them from the caller
- be transparent - have the same stdout as the called program
- return the exit code of the called program

The answer would be a functional script, here is the "prototype"

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=history.log
ORIGINAL=ls
touch ${LOGFILE}
echo "started" >>"${LOGFILE}"
ls "$@"
echo "ended with $?" >>"${LOGFILE}”
```

Comment: And where is the question part?

Comment: Asking for code, whether it's a link to a project or code itself, isn't an appropriate question here.

Comment: What is this doing that bash history doesn't do already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also at https://gist.github.com/2411440

```
#!/bin/bash
# install:
# * rename the original script to script.original
# * rename the wrapper.sh to script
# * DONE! all calls are going to be logged now
TIMESTAMP=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`

ME=`basename $0`
WRAPPED_COMMAND=$ME.original

echo "${TIMESTAMP} exec: $0 $@" >>${ME}.stdout.log

#${WRAPPED_COMMAND} "$@"|tee -a "${LOGFILE}"
${WRAPPED_COMMAND} "$@" > >(tee -a ${ME}.stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a ${ME}.stderr.tmp >&2)
RET=$?
TIMESTAMP_END=`date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"`

if [ -s ${ME}.stderr.tmp ] # if we have something logged to stderr (not usual)
then
    echo "${TIMESTAMP} exec: $0 $@" >>${ME}.stderr.log
    cat  >> ${ME}.stderr.log
    echo "${TIMESTAMP_END} retured: ${RET}" >>${ME}.stderr.log
fi
rm  -f "${ME}.stderr.tmp"

echo "${TIMESTAMP_END} retured: ${RET}" >>${ME}.stdout.log
exit $RET
```